# Hover event action not unhooking on resize of browser window

Tags: jquery

I have a div that displays a menu on hover or onclick, depending on browser width.

onhover or onclick at a larger resolution, the menu should hover over existing content.

onclick at a smaller resolution, the menu should not hover but rather slide down.

everything is working as intended when initially loaded into the specific screen widths.

The problem occurs when the browser screen is manually resized. If it's at a larger resolution and the menu button is hovered over, diplaying the menu - all fine. But if the screen is then manually resized to a smaller width, instead of the menu sliding onclick, it hovers over existing content on hover (though works correctly as a slider onclick).

If i then refresh the window, it works as intended as a slider.

I'm guessing the browser isn't unhooking the hover event when the screen is resized, even though i am checking for the width upon hover as well as onclick and determing actions depending on that. what am i doing wrong?

here is my code: - #MainMenu is the button being clicked, .nav-container is the nav div

```
        $('#MainMenu').on('click mouseover',function(event){

                    var wi = $(window).width();

                    //If between 768 and 979 pixels, menu should be overlay/onhover/onclick

                    if(wi >= 768 && wi <=979) {

                        /* Show menu on hover */

                        $("#MainMenu, .nav-container").hover(function() {
                            $('.nav-container').show();
                        });

                        /* Hide menu on mouseout */

                        $('.header-content').mouseleave(function() {
                            $('.nav-container').hide();
                        });

                        /* Nav should also open/close onclick */
                        $('.nav-container').toggle();

                    }

                    //Otherwise, menu should slide down but only onclick

                    else {
                        if(event.type=="click") {
                            $('.nav-container').slideToggle();
                        }   

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$('#MainMenu').on('click mouseover',function(event){
        /*  Show menu on hover */
        $("#MainMenu, .nav-container").hover(function() {

            var wi = $(window).width();

            //If between 768 and 979 pixels, menu should be overlay/onhover/onclick
            if(wi >= 768 && wi <=979) {
                $('.nav-container').show();
            }
            else{ //Otherwise, menu should slide down but only onclick
                if(event.type=="click") {
                    $('.nav-container').slideToggle();
                }   
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Basically, you are checking for the width before you trigger the show and hide.

Side note: your `hover` event is binding on every `click mouseover`, that's likely not what you want.